# fence_virtualbox failed to reboot

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, pacemaker, high-availability, pcs

I’m learning how to fence pacemaker using fence_virtualbox from [[ClusterLabs] Fence agent for VirtualBox](https://lists.clusterlabs.org/pipermail/users/2017-February/021382.html), but I can’t get it working. When I try to run `stonith_admin –-reboot <node id>` it failed.

Currently, my setup is:

```
Node ID:        VM name:
orcllinux1      OL7
orcllinux2      OL7_2
```

I set it up using:

`pcs stonith create fence_vbox fence_virtualbox pcmk_host_map=”orcllinux1:OL7,orcllinux2:OL7_2” pcmk_host_list=”orcllinux1,orcllinux2” pcmk_host_check=static_list ipaddr=”192.168.57.1” login=”root”`

But `stonith_admin –-reboot <node id>` resulting in this error:
[image: Error]

I tried to use the fence_virtualbox manually using:

```
fence_virtualbox -s 192.168.57.1 -p OL7 -o=reboot
```

and it succeeded.

Is my stonith create syntax wrong? What's the right syntax if it's wrong?

Comment: I resort to change my virtual guest name accordingly with my node ID (orcllinux1 and orcllinux2). Then I add it using `pcs stonith create fence_vbox fence_virtualbox ipaddr=”192.168.57.1"`. This works perfectly when I run `stonith_admin –-reboot <node id>` but still doesn't answer my question (if it's different name with node ID). Any further help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`pcs stonith create myfence_vbox fence_vbox identity_file=/root/.ssh/id_rsa ipaddr=192.168.1.20 login=bk201 host_os=linux pcmk_host_map="node1:6051319b-6d94-4469-93ec-b918d047e849 node2:8cbc8c1c-2da0-4ae6-a902-fcc15dfa7745"`

To get a list of UUIDs for each VM, run:
`fence_vbox -o list -l bk201 -x -a 192.168.1.20 -k /root/.ssh/id_rsa`

Tested with `stonith_admin --reboot node2` from node1 and node2 rebooted.

Comment: This use fence_vbox stonith agent instead of fence_virtualbox. I don't know if it has the same functionality.

Comment: Ah yeah it is different, this fence_vbox is the one supplied by Clusterlabs: https://github.com/ClusterLabs/fence-agents/tree/master/agents/vbox